# Wrong authentication Login in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, authentication, redirect, react-router

I am trying to do a Login page. So I have also protected route which is an admin page. So the first page is Login and if the user is successfully logged in, it should be redirect to '/admin'. For this, my Login component is:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";
import useForm from "../components/LoginForm/useForm";
import validate from "components/LoginForm/validate";
import redtruck from "../assets/img/red-truck.png";
import auth from "../Authentication/auth";

import { withRouter } from "react-router";

const Login = ({ submitForm, history }) => {
  const [isSubmitted, setIsSubmitted] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const [login, setLogin] = useState(false);

  async function submitForm() {
    setIsSubmitted(true);
    try {
      await fetchLogin(values.email, values.password);
      auth.login(() => {
        history.push("/admin");
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("wrong pass");
    }
  }

  const { handleChange, values, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm(
    submitForm,
    validate
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (localStorage.getItem("user-info")) {
      submitForm();
    }
  }, []);
  const fetchLogin = async (email, password) => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const res = await Axios({
        method: "POST",
        url: `url`,
        headers: {
        },
        data: {
          user_email: email,
          user_password: password,
        },
      });
      if (res.status === 200) {
        setLogin(true);
        localStorage.setItem("user-info", JSON.stringify(res.data));
      }
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (err) {
      setError(err.message);
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <div className="form-container">
          <div className="form-content-left">
            <img className="form-img" src={redtruck} alt="spaceship" />
          </div>
          <div className="form-content-right">
            <h1>SIGN IN</h1>
            <form className="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <div className="form-inputs">
                <label htmlFor="email" className="form-label">
                  Email address
                </label>
                <input
                  id="signin-email"
                  type="email"
                  name="email"
                  placeholder="Enter email"
                  className="form-input"
                  value={values.email}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                />
                {errors.email && <p>{errors.email}</p>}
              </div>
              <div className="form-inputs">
                <label htmlFor="password" className="form-label">
                  Password
                </label>
                <input
                  id="signin-password"
                  type="password"
                  name="password"
                  placeholder="Password"
                  className="form-input"
                  value={values.password}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                />
                {errors.password && <p>{errors.password}</p>}
                {login ? "" : <p>The password or the email is wrong</p>}
              </div>
              <button
                variant="primary"
                type="submit"
                className="form-input-btn"
              >
                LOGIN
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default withRouter(Login);
```

So, my problem is even though the password or the email is wrong, it is still redirecting to '/admin'. So, I dont want it to redirect to the page '/admin' when the credentials are wrong but also I want to show error message if the password or email is wrong. If you could give me any suggestion on this, I will be really glad.

Thanks...

Comment: Did you Solved it ?

Comment: With you solution with wrong pass and email I am still redirected to /admin page

Answer (score 1):

You should only use the `onSubmit` callback from the form.

At the moment, you are calling the `handleSubmit` and `loginButton` functions when the user clicks login. Remove the `loginButton` callback and execute your logic in the `onSubmit` callback from the form. Also be sure to `event.preventDefault()` at the beginning of the form callback.

If your button has `type="submit"`, it will submit the form automatically.

The `submitForm` function should looks something like this:

```
  async function submitForm() {
      setIsSubmitted(true);
      try {
          await fetchLogin();
          auth.login(() => {
            history.push("/admin");
          });
      } catch (e) {
          // User is not logged
      }
  }
```

And just throw in the `fetchLogin` function if the login fails

Comment: I edited the code and applied the same that you told me but still the same happening. Am I missing something?

Comment: @magicbean, did you remove the callback on the login button? Did you throw in the fetchLogin function when the login fails?

Comment: I did remove the callback and I remove whole loginButton function, so fetchLogin function removed also with it.

Comment: @magicbean, you need to implement your login logic in the try and throw if it fails, if it does not throw, it will go to the next line and call your history push

Comment: actually what I am trying to implement, If it is 200 which means login is success, then I setLogin to true. So I believe I need to check if the login is true or false in try catch but how ?

Answer (score 0):

You should either use `loginButton()` or `submitForm()` to handle the login.

Answer (score 0):

Use e.preventDefault() default like this to prevent auto submit. Use the Button Click to Submit the form.

You can use Button Click Event and Remove form submit.

```
                <button
                variant="primary"
                type="submit"
                className="form-input-btn"
                onClick={handleLoginSubmit}
              >
                LOGIN
              </button>

    const handleLoginSubmit = async (event) => {

     event.preventDefault();
     
     setIsSubmitted(true);
     
    try {
      await fetchLogin(values.email, values.password);
      auth.login(() => {
        history.push("/admin");
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("wrong pass");
    }
     

   }
```

Comment: The OP want to do it in React, this is pure js